# Eigenvalues of an endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$ v_{1},v_{2},v_{3} \in\mathbb{R} $, where $ v_{1} = (1, 0, 0),v_{1} = (1, 1, -1),v_{3} = (1, -2, 3) $

$ \varepsilon $ is the standard basis of $ \mathbb{Q^3}$  and $ \beta = (v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}) $ is an other basis of $ \mathbb{Q^3}$

Show that there is exactly one endomorphism $ \varphi: \mathbb{Q^3} \to \mathbb{Q^3} $ with the following properties:

1. $v_{1} $ is the eigenvector of $\varphi$ to the eigenvalue $-2$
2. $v_{2} $ is the eigenvector of $\varphi$ to the eigenvalue $0$
3. $v_{3} $ is the eigenvector of $\varphi$ to the eigenvalue $1$

Well I showed that the vectors $v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}$ are a basis of $ \mathbb{Q^3}$ and I guess that I have to find the transformation matrix of the endomorphisms $ \varphi: \mathbb{Q^3} \to \mathbb{Q^3} $ and as I get it I can calculate the characteristic polynomial and the eigenvalues and eigenvectors also. But how will I get the matrix of this endomorphism?

I am struggling with this question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you give a matrix P such as $P^{-1} M P $ is diagonal ? (M is the matrix of an endomorphism $\varphi$ that verifies the properties).

Comment: You're on the right track. Try to find the matrix of this endomorphism with respect to the basis consisting of eigenvectors (you should get a diagonal matrix). Alternatively, suppose there are two such endomorphisms, can you prove they are the same? (Hint: If two linear maps act the same on a basis, they are equal).

Comment: Let $\psi$ with the same properties. Let $x=x_1v_1+x_2v_2+x_3v_3$. Then $$\psi (x)=x_1\psi (v_1)+x_2\psi (v_2)+x_3\psi (v_3)=...=\varphi (x)$$

Comment: thank you for the hints but I'm still struggling how do these help me to prove the properties